# Heat-Sink-Connection LED: NVSL219CT

Tags: led, high-power

I am currently planning my new PCB with 2 LEDs (NVSL219CT). I would operate the LEDs with 1.5A. What I could not find in the datasheet: Is it allowed to connect the HeatSink to the ground plane?

Datasheet: https://led-ld.nichia.co.jp/api/data/spec/led/NVSL219CT-E(3484H)R70%20R8000%20R9050.pdf

Comment: Welcome! Please link to the datasheet.

Comment: I don't see anything in the spec for voltage between heatsink connection and anode/cathode, but it appears to be floating. Ask Nichia?

Answer (score 0):

Page 12 of the datasheet you linked shows the pinout of the LED, which indicates quite clearly that the heat-sinking pad is floating:

[image: LED pinout]

This means that you can freely connect the pad to your ground plane, assuming that the voltage difference between it and the LED's connections is within reasonable limits (i.e. not hundreds of volts).

Comment: Thank you for your help!